# Static Blog Generator - Python Flask - ValueError

Tags: python, flask, github-pages, atom-feed

I'm trying to build a static blog generator using the python flask framework and I'm running into a problem. The goal is to freeze my Flask application into a set of static files using Frozen-Flask so that I can push the files to Github Pages. The python script works fine but the issue arises when I enter a build command into the terminal.

Allow me to detail my steps below:

Command Line Input:

```
python generator.py build
```

Command Line Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generator.py", line 152, in <module>
    freezer.freeze()
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 166, in freeze
    new_filename = self._build_one(url)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/blog/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 280, in _build_one
    % (response.status, url))
ValueError: Unexpected status '500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR' on URL /feed.atom
```

I checked the python documentation for ValueError to see what it meant.

> exception **ValueError**
>
> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that
>   has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is
>   not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

Here are the lines of code from the python script mentioned in the terminal output:

```
@app.route('/feed.atom')
def feed():
    feed = AtomFeed('Recent Articles',
                    feed_url=request.url,
                    url=request.url_root)
    posts = blog.posts[:10]
    title = lambda p: '%s: %s' % (p.title, p.subtitle) if hasattr(p, 'subtitle') else p.title
    for post in posts:
        feed.add(title(post),
            unicode(post.html),
            content_type='html',
            author=post.author.name,
            url=post.url(_external=True),
            updated=post.date,
            published=post.date)
    return feed.get_response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'build':
        freezer.freeze()
    else:
        post_files = [post.filepath for post in blog.posts]
        app.run(port=8000, debug=True, extra_files=post_files)
```

If you need to view the entire python script:

```
import os
import sys
import collections

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, abort, request
from flask.ext.frozen import Freezer
from werkzeug import cached_property
from werkzeug.contrib.atom import AtomFeed
import markdown
import yaml


FREEZER_BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'
FREEZER_DESTINATION_IGNORE = ['.git*', 'CNAME']
DOMAIN = 'example.com'
POSTS_FILE_EXTENSION = '.md'


class SortedDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, items=None, key=None, reverse=False):
        self._items = {}
        self._keys = []
        if key:
            self._key_fn = lambda k: key(self._items[k])
        else:
            self._key_fn = lambda k: self._items[k]
        self._reverse = reverse

        if items is not None:
            self.update(items)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._items[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._items[key] = value
        if key not in self._keys:
            self._keys.append(key)
            self._keys.sort(key=self._key_fn, reverse=self._reverse)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self._items.pop(key)
        self._keys.remove(key)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._keys)

    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self._keys:
            yield key

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self._items)

class Blog(object):
    def __init__(self, app, root_dir='', file_ext=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.file_ext = file_ext if file_ext is not None else app.config['POSTS_FILE_EXTENSION']
        self._app = app
        self._cache = SortedDict(key=lambda p: p.date, reverse=True)
        self._initialize_cache()

    @property
    def posts(self):
        if self._app.debug:
            return self._cache.values()
        else:
            return [post for post in self._cache.values() if post.published]

    def get_post_or_404(self, path):
        """Returns the Post object for the given path or raises a NotFound exception
        """
        try:
            return self._cache[path]
        except KeyError:
            abort(404)

    def _initialize_cache(self):
        """Walks the root directory and adds all posts to the cache
        """
        for (root, dirpaths, filepaths) in os.walk(self.root_dir):
            for filepath in filepaths:
                filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)
                if ext == self.file_ext:
                    path = os.path.join(root, filepath).replace(self.root_dir, '')
                    post = Post(path, root_dir=self.root_dir)
                    self._cache[post.urlpath] = post


class Post(object):
    def __init__(self, path, root_dir=''):
        self.urlpath = os.path.splitext(path.strip('/'))[0]
        self.filepath = os.path.join(root_dir, path.strip('/'))
        self.published = False
        self._initialize_metadata()

    @cached_property
    def html(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'r') as fin:
            content = fin.read().split('\n\n', 1)[1].strip()
        return markdown.markdown(content, extensions=['codehilite'])

    def url(self, _external=False):
        return url_for('post', path=self.urlpath, _external=_external)

    def _initialize_metadata(self):
        content = ''
        with open(self.filepath, 'r') as fin:
            for line in fin:
                if not line.strip():
                    break
                content += line
        self.__dict__.update(yaml.load(content))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
blog = Blog(app, root_dir='posts')
freezer = Freezer(app)

@app.template_filter('date')
def format_date(value, format='%B %d, %Y'):
    return value.strftime(format)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', posts=blog.posts)

@app.route('/blog/<path:path>/')
def post(path):
    post = blog.get_post_or_404(path)
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)

@app.route('/feed.atom')
def feed():
    feed = AtomFeed('Recent Articles',
                    feed_url=request.url,
                    url=request.url_root)
    posts = blog.posts[:10]
    title = lambda p: '%s: %s' % (p.title, p.subtitle) if hasattr(p, 'subtitle') else p.title
    for post in posts:
        feed.add(title(post),
            unicode(post.html),
            content_type='html',
            author=post.author.name,
            url=post.url(_external=True),
            updated=post.date,
            published=post.date)
    return feed.get_response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'build':
        freezer.freeze()
    else:
        post_files = [post.filepath for post in blog.posts]
        app.run(port=8000, debug=True, extra_files=post_files)
```

I'm still a newbie when it comes to flask, so I'm not entirely sure how to fix this problem. If someone could help it would be much appreciated. Let me know if you need more information; I've tried to be as detailed as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Is that making a request to `/feed.atom` on a server that you are running? If so, can you check the logs on that server?

Comment: Well the line `freezer.freeze()` is making a request to `/feed.atom` on *some* server and that server is responding with a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Flask-Frozen is raising the `ValueError` because your `/feed.xml` endpoint is returning a 500, Internal Server Error, rather than a 200, Success response.  Flask-Frozen assumes that you don't want to save the result of a 400 or 500-level error, and raises an error so you can look into the underlying problem.

To see the error visit `/feed.xml` in your browser and see what the error response is.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I ran the python script and appended `/feed.atom` to the url and it took me to the in browser python debugger. The ValueError was due to the author variable in `/feed.atom` route because it wasn't defined in the Post class; so I hard coded the author variable and it cleared up that problem. However, now I'm getting another **AttributeError**: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'. Does this mean I should do a datetime import in my script?

Comment: your the atom feed is expecting a datetime object, but I believe post.date is just  a date object so you need to and the time. If you `from datetime import datetime` and then replace `post.date` with `datetime.combine(post.date, datetime.min.time())`, it should work. Mine does. Hope it helps